# Demo a question ask by a normal persion oke

Tags: laravel

A user can ask many questions.

How many = User.question_set.all().count()
A question can be bookmarked by many users (once per user).

How many = Question.bookmark_set.all().count()
How many users have bookmarked the all questions asked by a single user?

How many = ???
My models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField()

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use some framework like Laravel its defined some relationship like hasMany